# How do you filter for new records in a table relative to a selected date in PBI?

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

I have the following table

```
Id date
 A  2022-01-31
 B  2022-01-31
 C  2022-01-31
 D  2022-02-28
 A  2022-02-28
 B  2022-02-28
 C  2022-02-28
 E  2022-03-31
 D  2022-03-31
 A  2022-03-31
 B  2022-03-31
 C  2022-03-31
```

I have 2 date filters D_start amd D_end for start date and one for end date. I also have a table visual showing this data. The date filters are from a DimDate table and arent connected to the avove tabe in the data model and only serve to have dates selectable.

We can see ID D is new in Feb and E is new in Mar. I want the data on the page to be filtered for only new records based on the two dates selected.

ex)
If D_start = 2022-01-31 and D_end = 2022-02-28, the table visual I want my table to display:

```
ID Date
 D 2022-02-28
```

If D_start = 2022-01-31 and D_end = 2022-03-31, the table visual I want my table to display

```
 ID Date
  D 2022-02-28
  E 2022-03-31
```

If D_start = 2022-02-28 and D_end = 2022-03-31, the table visual I want my table to display

```
 ID Date
  E 2022-03-31
```

Other than ETL-ing a seperate dataset of only originations by date key, I'm not too sure how to accomplish this with DAX expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Use this measure as a date column (instead of 'date') in your visual and as a filter in a filtering module. Set the Non-blank value in the filter.

```
YourMeasure=

VAR StartDay = MAX('Start'[Date]) ' your Start DimDate table 
VAR EndDay=MIN('End'[Date])  ' your End DimDate table 
Var firstDay =
        FIRSTNONBLANK(
            'YourDataTable'[date]
            ,COUNTROWS('YourDataTable')
        )

VAR lastDay =

        LASTNONBLANK(
            'YourDataTable'[date]
            ,COUNTROWS('YourDataTable')
        )

RETURN
    IF(
        OR(
            firstDay<StartDay
            ,lastDay>EndDay
        )
        ,BLANK()
        ,firstDay
    )
```